# predict statsmodel argument Error

Tags: python, statsmodels

I am trying to predict outofsample values for an array. 
Python code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARIMA

    dates = pd.date_range('2012-07-09','2012-07-30')
    series = [43.,32.,63.,98.,65.,78.,23.,35.,78.,56.,45.,45.,56.,6.,63.,45.,64.,34.,76.,34.,14.,54.]
    res = pd.Series(series, index=dates)
    r = ARIMA(res,(1,2,0))
    pred = r.predict(start='2012-07-31', end='2012-08-31')
```

I am getting this error.I see I have given two argument but compiler return I have given 3.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "XXXXXXXXX/testfile.py", line 12, in <module>
    pred = r.predict(start='2012-07-31', end='2012-08-31')
TypeError: predict() takes at least 2 arguments (3 given)
```

Please help

Comment: The error message is strange -- clearly `3` is *at least `2`*, so it doesn't make a lot of sense. Are you positive this is the exact message you receive?

Comment: Yes, I am sure. I have updated the complete error

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The call signature of `ARIMA.predict` is

```
predict(self, params, start=None, end=None, exog=None, dynamic=False)
```

Thus, when you call `r.predict(start='2012-07-31', end='2012-08-31')`, `self` gets bound to `r`, and values are bound to `start` and `end` but the required positional arument `params` does not get bound. That is why you get the error

```
TypeError: predict() takes at least 2 arguments (3 given)
```

Unfortunately the error message is misleading. The "3 given" refer to `r`, `start` and `end`. The "2 arguments" refer to the two required arguments, `self` and `params`.
The problem is that the *required* positional argument `params` was not given.

To fix the problem, you need parameters. Usually you find those parameters by fitting:

```
r = r.fit()
```

before calling

```
pred = r.predict(start='2012-07-31', end='2012-08-31')
```

`r.fit()` returns a `statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARIMAResultsWrapper` which 
have the parameters "baked in" so calling `ARIMAResultWrapper.fit` does not require passing `params`.

---

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARIMA

dates = pd.date_range('2012-07-09','2012-07-30')
series = [43.,32.,63.,98.,65.,78.,23.,35.,78.,56.,45.,45.,56.,6.,63.,45.,64.,34.,76.,34.,14.,54.]
res = pd.Series(series, index=dates)
r = ARIMA(res,(1,2,0))
r = r.fit()
pred = r.predict(start='2012-07-31', end='2012-08-31')
print(pred)
```

yields

```
2012-07-31   -39.067222
2012-08-01    26.902571
2012-08-02   -17.027333
...
2012-08-29     0.532946
2012-08-30     0.532447
2012-08-31     0.532780
Freq: D, dtype: float64
```