# Predict with Triple Exponential Smoothing using ExponentialSmoothing of statsmodels in python

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, statsmodels

I'm working on the forecast of some time series and I need to compare different methods using python. Practically I need to generate some predictions using the Triple Exponential Smoothing, and I'm using [this library](http://www.statsmodels.org/stable/index.html) and the relative functions like [this](http://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.tsa.holtwinters.ExponentialSmoothing.html?highlight=exponentialsmoothing).
My time series has this format, as pd.Series object:

```
    Date Close
2016-04-11 01:17:04    -10.523793
2016-04-11 07:25:13     -5.352295
2016-04-11 22:40:11     92.556003
2016-04-13 05:06:31     -1.769866
2016-04-13 05:17:50     -2.330789
2016-04-14 08:43:09     17.636638
2016-04-17 21:15:12     -0.454655
2016-04-19 06:10:04     -0.026375
2016-04-19 06:10:04     -0.175647
...
```

I wrote these lines in python:

```
from statsmodels.tsa.holtwinters import ExponentialSmoothing
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd
train_size = int(len(myTimeSeries) * 0.66)
train, test = myTimeSeries[1:train_size], myTimeSeries[train_size:]

model = ExponentialSmoothing(train)
model_fit = model.fit()
dict=model.params
params=np.array(list(dict.items()))
dates=test.index.astype(str)
pred = model.predict(params,start=dates[2], end=dates[-1])
plt.plot(train, label='Train')
plt.plot(test, label='Test')
plt.plot(pred, label='Holt-Winters')
plt.legend(loc='best')
```

I had a problem with the function `model.predict` so I added the param values as required, getting them from the class `model`, after its `fit`. I'm not sure if I did well but I've not found so much [around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36717603/predict-statsmodel-argument-error). Moreover I got a problem in setting the start date (and maybe also the end). It returns this: `KeyError: 'The`start`argument could not be matched to a location related to the index of the data.'` As I found [here](https://discuss.analyticsvidhya.com/t/time-series-analysis/67474), I also moved the start date of the prediction to the third value, that is the index [2] of the test dataset. I got the same if I set [0],[1], etc... What's wrong with that?

As you can see, myTimeSeries has not a fixed frequency set, but the collection of the value is random. I've found different tutorials, like [this](https://medium.com/datadriveninvestor/how-to-build-exponential-smoothing-models-using-python-simple-exponential-smoothing-holt-and-da371189e1a1), [this other one](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2018/02/time-series-forecasting-methods/), or [this about theory](https://grisha.org/blog/2016/02/17/triple-exponential-smoothing-forecasting-part-iii/), but they are not in the same conditions: I don't know any news (trend, seasonal frequency, etc..) about my dataset. I've not found any violated hypotheses for this: warn me if I'm wrong. I used to consider my theory guide, what I've found [here](https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/pmc/section4/pmc435.htm). Moreover, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36717603/predict-statsmodel-argument-error?noredirect=1&lq=1) covers a similar problem but not exactly the same.

Comment: In `model.fit()` what are you fitting? You have to pass the training x and y data to this. Also why are you starting from index ` in `myTimeSeries[1:train_size]`? The index starts from `0` in python. You should replace it with `myTimeSeries[:train_size]`

Comment: Also replace `model_fit = model.fit()` by `model.fit()`

Comment: @Bazingaa, nothing changes. About ```model_fit = model.fit()``` it returns the object of the fitting parameters and you can save or not somewhere, like ```model_fit ``` About ```myTimeSeries[:train_size]``` it can be right, but it does not solve the real problem

Comment: model.fit() without any parameters is not correct. Writing model.fit() and then `model.predict(params,start=dates[2], end=dates[-1])` makes no sense whatsoever

Comment: ok, but what's the solution? Just consider this: if I run `model_fit = model.fit()` , `dict=model.params`,  then dict contains this `{'damping_slope': nan,
 'initial_level': 1.6674941946357755,
 'initial_seasons': array([], dtype=float64),
 'initial_slope': nan,
 'lamda': None,
 'remove_bias': False,
 'smoothing_level': 0.0,
 'smoothing_seasonal': nan,
 'smoothing_slope': nan,
 'use_boxcox': False}  ` , but if I don't make run the `fit()` function, there is no params generated, in fact it returns this: ` AttributeError: 'ExponentialSmoothing' object has no attribute 'params' `

Answer (score 3):

I think maybe you just want:

```
pred = model_fit.forecast(len(test))
```

You can't use dates here for specifying the forecast period because your date index doesn't have a frequency associated with it, so the best you can do is just indicate the number of forecasts that you want.

Comment: ok, but how do I arrange the generated data with the train and test samples? If they have dates, and `pred` not, how can I compare them in the plot? Thanks

Comment: `pred` is a numpy array, so you can convert it to a Pandas array with the same index as `test` if you want. (like `pred = pd.Series(model_fit.forecast(len(test)), index=test.index)`.

Comment: Ok, even if the correct command is: `pred = pd.Series(model_fit.forecast(len(test)).values, index=test.index)`

Comment: I got this: https://screenshots.firefox.com/OLbqQpw9ub3bCSDP/labs.cognitiveclass.ai Do you think it is a good prediction? I cannot see any spikes up or down for the forecast values (green in the picture), as test values have (orange in the picture)